# How to reload routing table on Centos without lost network service

Tags: linux

I've add 1 route in configuration network file, how to reload routing table on Centos without lost network service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to reload routing table without lost network service (I think you mean you don't have to use `service network restart` command to make the changes). If you have any change to network configuration file, you need to restart `networking service` to apply new configuration.

In your case, you can add the config (i.e new route, new gateway...) manually, so you will have new config running.

But this config will be lost if you reboot server. To make it persitent, you must add this config to network configuration file.

Comment: Don't do this if your running containers. This breaks some in fundamental way forcing you to have to redeploy said containers. I don't like this but it's the only way I have found that reloads the routes and doesn't break containers. `ifdown eth0; ifup eth0`

Answer (score 12):

Static routes are defined into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<interface name>` files.
(see [Centos documentation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html))

To apply one of these files :

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-routes <interface name>
```

That will not reload the rules, that will just reread the configuration and execute `route add` commands (so no route deletion).

I do not recommand to use the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifdown-routes` to delete routes, unless you are sure you can still connect after deleting that routes. Better use the `route del` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `route` or `ip route` commands to change the routing table dynamically.

To test if the changes you made to the configuration files are correct and won't cause failure at the next (un)planned reboot, a `service network restart` should be scheduled at a convenient time too.